# emberjs component communication

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components

I have some trouble with component communication. Lets say I have 3 nested components.

Parent `{{component-a}}` -> which has child `{{component-b}}` -> which has child `{{component-c}}`.

How can I access `component-c` directly from `component-a`, if `component-c` is not rendered.
Is this even possible.
Thank you

Comment: if my answer helped you to solve the question, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll generally want to use a service for communication across different trees of components or for 'sending data up from a child component'

Services are very easy to test.

Using data-down-actions-up would also work, but beyond a couple layers is known as prop drilling. Prop drilling makes components hard to maintain due to over-inter-connectness

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Ember uses a data down action up pattern. This means that if you want to send data from a component to its child you pass it by a parameter, but if you want the opposite direction you should send an action with the data. And when you have 3 components you pass by the one in the middle and this one will keep on relaying the information.

You can find more information [here](https://emberigniter.com/getting-started-ember-cli-data-down-actions-up-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for clarification Ipinto.eu.